# How to make a arduino uno act as a HID device?

Tags: arduino

I bought Arduino and want to make a Arduino macro keyboard, but when I wanted it to write something I naturally write `Keyboard.begin()` and #include <Keyboard.h>. And when I want to check if the code is correct it throw errors. It said that I don't have written #include <Keyboard.h>.

This is my code if someone matters:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {7, 6, 5, 4}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {11, 10, 9, 8}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);

   Keyboard.begin()
}
```

Comment: The answers have addressed your HID concerns. You're getting the compile error because you haven't created any `Keyboard` object. Yes, you included the header file, but you didn't make an object like you did with the `Keypad` object. Add a `Keyboard keyboard = Keyboard(..stuff...);` line, and use `keyboard.begin()` in `setup` and the compile error might be solved.

Comment: the library is not for Uno. it is for Leonardo, Micro or SAMD Arduinos. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples#keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do such thing without any additional driver.

Arduino Uno uses serial connection that runs from UART to USB conventer. That means it is not a real USB connection. If you try to compile it on the board, that has this real connection (f.e. any of ATMega32U4-based boards), the error won't appear.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use a board that's designed for what you're trying to do, such as the Teensy 2.0.

But, when has that stopped us before?

The UNO can be forced to act as an HID device by using a non-standard driver.
https://github.com/NicoHood/HID

Comment: or maybe Leonardo.